# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jsp.logAdaptor_jsp

Tags: java, classnotfoundexception, cruisecontrol

I'm trying to build my jar on Weblogic 10.3.6 but I'm getting this error:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jsp.logAdaptor_jsp
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperLoader.findClass(JasperLoader.java:188)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperLoader.loadClass(JasperLoader.java:174)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperLoader.loadClass(JasperLoader.java:106)
    at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.load(JspCompilationContext.java:623)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.getServlet(JspServletWrapper.java:176)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:356)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:470)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:364)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:487)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:362)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:181)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:729)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:405)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:206)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:114)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:324)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:505)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:829)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:513)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:211)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:380)
    at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:395)
    at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:488
```

Please, if you need another thing just let me know.

Comment: Please post the full stack trace

Comment: This is all trace, i'm trying to build from an application developed by our company. It doesn't show any other trace.

Comment: Is is a Maven project? If so  check the the scopes of the jsp dependency. Try to change its scope to 'provided' or remove that dependency entirely and try to deploy it again. Be sure to clean cache and deploy it.

Answer (score 0):

I now solved the problem. After restarting Clearcase CruiseControl service, it started to give a real error. But i have no idea why it has given that mistake before.